# is there a way to use Pytion3, django2.0.2 and MySql together on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, mysql-python

I searched alot to install python3.6 and django2.0.2 with MySql server, but I got nothing because django2.0.2 framework doesn't support MySqldb yet.

Comment: Where did you get the conclusion of django2.0.2 framework doesn't support MySqldb yet?

Comment: I think I was wrong. but know I can use it with Django when installing its required dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST Framework does support MySQL engine.

> Django supports MySQL 5.5 and higher.
>
> Django’s inspectdb feature uses the information_schema database, which
>   contains detailed data on all database schemas.
>
> Django expects the database to support Unicode (UTF-8 encoding) and
>   delegates to it the task of enforcing transactions and referential
>   integrity. It is important to be aware of the fact that the two latter
>   ones aren’t actually enforced by MySQL when using the MyISAM storage
>   engine, see the next section.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/

Follow the link to setup the configuration